# calling derived methods on a baseclass collection

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism, covariance

I have one abstract class named A, and other classes (B, C, D, E, ...) that implements A.
My derived classes are holding values of different types.
I also have a list of A objects.

```
    abstract class A { }
    class B : class A
    {
      public int val {get;private set;}
    }
    class C : class A
    {
      public double val {get;private set;}
    }
    class D : class A
    {
      public string val {get;private set;}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          List list = new List { new B(), new C(), new D(), new E() };
          // ... 

          foreach (A item in list)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value is: {0}", item.val);
          }
        }
    }
```

...where the .val is not known by the base-class ofc.

How can i get this dynamic behaviour? I don't want to use getType in a long switch/if-statements.

Comment: The fact that the classes inherit from `A` doesn't matter here - `A` doesn't have a `val`, so the subclasses' `val`s are not related. You might as well just use `object` as the base class. I guess this sounds like you want to use `dynamic`, if you're using C# 4.0+

Comment: @Blorgbeard One small correction. c#4.0 as well as .net 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

abstract class A
{
    public abstract dynamic Val { get;   set; }

}
class B : A
{
    public override dynamic Val { get;  set; }
}
class C : A
{
    public override dynamic Val { get;  set; }
}
class D : A
{
    public override dynamic Val { get;  set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<A> { new B(), new C(), new D() };
        // ... 

        foreach (A item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value is: {0}", item.Val));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had actually forgotten about `dynamic` in C# because I've never actually declared something `dynamic` and only ever make use of it with `ViewBag` in an MVC app.  Using it still doesn't quite get what the OP is asking for because the overridden members are not strongly typed, so code using them will still have to cast the result and they will not restrict what can be assigned to them.  It's as close as you'll get though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so use object

Comment: The type is internally set in the derived classes when assigning values. The nice thing is, that you can set any type of value, and the "override" is possible since it is the same type (dynamic) in both, base and derived class. With the overridden values (get) you can call the toString() with polymorphic behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the string representation of val i recoment overriding ToString in each of the sub classes

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return val.ToString();
}
```

either way if you want the data in a sub class you need to represent it in the base class as some type they all have in common (like object). and you could do it like this

```
abstract class A 
{
    public abstract object GetValue();
}
class B : class A
{
    public int val {get;private set;}
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `val` is not a member of the base class then you can't access it on a reference of that type.  Those three derived classes may all have a member named `val` but it is NOT the same member so it cannot be treated like it is.  What you could do is declare a generic class and make that `val` property of the generic type but then you couldn't create a List of that type.  Basically, what you want to do is not possible.  It's not based on inheritance and it's not based on generics.  It sounds convenient but it's not logical.

Answer (score 1):

```
 abstract class A { public string val { get; set; } }
class B :  A
{
  public int val {get;private set;}
}
class C :  A
{
  public double val {get;private set;}
}
class D :  A
{
  public string val {get;private set;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object> { new B(), new C(), new D() };
      // ... 

      foreach (A item in list)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value is: {0}", item.val));
      }
    }
}
```