# Call a method that is present only in some derived types

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, polymorphism

Imagine that you have a bunch of BaseType objects, and you have to do action A to all of them that are DerivedType B, C or D (and discard everything else). And you cannot do that to instances of BaseType because it does not have the method you need. In my case I need to assign a class to all controls of a certain type on an ASP.NET Webforms page, and the code looks like this:

```
if (myControl != null)
    {
        foreach (var input in myControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            input.CssClass = "my-class";
        }
        foreach (var input in myControl.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
        {
            input.CssClass = "my-class";
        }
        foreach (var input in myControl.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>())
        {
            input.CssClass = "my-class";
        }
        foreach (var input in myControl.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            input.CssClass = "my-class";
        }
    }
```

The alternative is to loop through all myControl.Controls and check if control as DerivedType X is or is not null for each control and each DerivedType I'm interested in... all that to do the exact same thing to each of them.

I wonder if I'm missing something obvious here (or if I just don't fully understand how polymorphism work). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747290/calling-derived-methods-on-a-baseclass-collection) gives a general idea on how to do that for custom classes, but unfortunately I'm stuck with Control.

Is there any more elegant way to do the task described above?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you probably mean _abstractions_ rather than _polymorphism_ because the client code generally does not care what the type is.  Your code is testing for object types so it isn't making good use of abstractions.  The web controls share similar _interfaces_ (e.g. a `CssClass` property) which is an example of _polymorphism_

Answer (score 1):

Actually its pretty simple.

The code you want to run is...

```
foreach(var child in control.Controls)
{
    var webChild = child as WebControl;
    if(webChild == null) return;
    webChild.CssClass = "Foo";
}
```

However Linq already has a "try-cast, filter" method called `.OfType<>()`.

You can use it like this

```
foreach(var child in control.Controls.OfType<WebControl>())
{
    child.CssClass = "Foo";
}
```

I recommend that you look into the class hierarchy when trying to work with polymorphism. You should either use the `Object Browser` or the MSDN references.

That should have told you that all the classes you were looking at inherits [WebControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), and it is on this class that `.CssClass` can be set on.

Comment: That would assign "Foo" to _all_ controls deriving from `WebControl` not just _"controls of a certain type"_ as the OP said.  Probably not a good use of abstractions and polymorphism anyway

Comment: @MickyD Nope. Just to all `WebControl`s. Where as the `Controls` collection contains `Control`s. Perhaps I've got the wrong end of the stick here, because the OP didn't give examples of the Controls he didn't want to have the value set for...But that is another test case for the TDD. :D

Comment: You cannot change the entry inside a foreach loop.

Comment: @Ephraim Erm...why not? Are you thinking about the age old Enumerable modified bug? I am very very confused by your comment...

Comment: You'd get a compile error: "Cannot assign to 'child' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'."

Comment: @Aron - now I'm confused as well :) But you are right, I should have made it clearer in the question itself. That is, I need to assign a class to certain control types (the ones listed in my example), but there are also other controls in the picture, which also inhehit from WebControl, but which I want to skip (e.g. Label and Panel), and your example affects them as well (or am I wrong?). Short of explicitly calling control.Controls.OfType() for each type I need, I don't know what else to try :(

Comment: @DarthVeyda You could add a `.Where(x => x.GetType() ...)`after the `.OfType<>()`...it seems to highlight how strange a piece of business logic you have...

Comment: @Aron - is it really that strange? To give it some context: I use that code to highlight required fields on the form; this is done from code behind because the set of required fields isn't constant and has to be calculated in code behind as well. And there are lots of fields, so just setting that class for each of them isn't a better option either. Hence the piece of code I have in the post :) Did you mean it to be like

`.OfType<WebControl>().Where(x => x.GetType == "TextBox" || x.GetType == "CheckBox" || (etc...))`

Comment: @DarthVeyda That is what css is for. Instead of setting the css class for each item. Set the class on the parent and then in your css style sheet create a selector for children of that parent which match a certain parameter...

Comment: @Aron - but how can I create a css selector that matches a parameter that, in turn, is calculated in code behind on each Page_Load?

Comment: @DarthVeyda That wasn't the question that you asked. Your question asked for all `Textbox` that is inside of `myControl`. Seems your question has very little to do with your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way to do what you want without other code modifications so yes you are right about looping and checking if the control is one of the derived types you are looking for.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myControl.Controls.Length; i++)
{
    if(myControl.Controls[i] is TextBox || myControl.Controls[i] is DropDownList || 
       myControl.Controls[i] is RadioButtonList || myControl.Controls[i] is Checkbox)
    {
        var webControl = myControl.Controls[i] as WebControl;
        webControl.CssClass = "my-class";
    }        
}
```

Comment: `Control` does not have the `.CssClass` property on it. Read the question. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control(v=vs.110).aspx